# Polymer: on-click event works in IE but not Chrome. How to fix?

Tags: javascript, events, onclick, polymer

I have an on-click event on an iron-icon which works just fine in IE but not Chrome.  Why wont this work?

```
<iron-icon icon="icons:foose" **on-click="doSomething"** hidden$="{{!foo.opened}}"></iron-icon>
<iron-icon icon="icons:ball" hidden$="{{foo.opened}}"></iron-icon>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try substituting on-click for on-tap, polymer docs generally recommend using Polymer gestures instead of mouse/touch events for the most reliable cross-platform results.
https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events.html#gestures